# Any good text editors that allow Javascript as a scripting language?

Tags: javascript, scripting, editor

I really enjoy JavaScript programming and have witnessed the power of being able to script your editor, like emacs. But been searching and can't find if there are any that support JavaScript. Not that I absolutely need JavaScript, it's just a preference you know. Anyone know any text editors that support Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

[Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) is built on XUL (the same technology that Firefox uses), and thus supports JavaScript macros as well as extensions.

Comment: Komodo is really nice, but I was thinking of something more on the lines of vim, gedit, or even emacs. I prefer simple editors to ide's any day

Answer (score 0):

[Kod](http://kodapp.com/) has an "integrated scripting environment based on Node.js". I haven't tried it yet though.

Comment: That would be perfect except that my main os is linux